# Как разделять орфографические и грамматические ошибки

Tags: орфография, грамматика

1. Пропуск мягкого знака в конце слова (вместо "целЬ" - "цел", вместо "поступитЬ" - "поступать") - это орфографическая или грамматическая ошибка?
2. Если пропущена буква в слове (гласная или согласная): вместо"телефон" - "тлефон" или "огурЕц" - "огурц"- орфогр. или грамматич. ошибка?
3. Если пропущен предлог между словами - орфогр. или грамматич. ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

**Ошибки бывают грамматические и орфографические,** кроме того, выделяются так называемые **"описки"**. Описка — это  разновидность орфографической ошибки, имеющая  различные причины, не связанные с орфографией непосредственно: невнимательность, неумение выделять звуки в потоке речи и др.

[Н. Д. Голев. Ошибка или описка - что хуже? | lingvo.asu.ru](http://lingvo.asu.ru/golev/articles/v97.html)

"Описка отличается от орфографической ошибки, и очень резко. Если человек сделал ошибку, то он может десятки раз спокойно перечитать текст, видеть свою ошибку - и все же не заметить и не исправить. Или исправить, лишь припомнив орфографическое правило, иногда с трудом. Описку при внимательном чтении сам пишущий замечает без всяких правил".

**1) Цел вместо цель** — орфографическая ошибка, которая в действительности может быть опиской (мягкий звук на конце слова всегда обозначается мягким знаком, кроме шипящих).

**2) Поступить вместо поступать** — грамматическая ошибка (неправильный вид глагола).

**3) Тлефон и огурц** — описка, но при большой частотности таких ошибок требует коррекции слухового восприятия звуков.

**4) пропущен предлог между словами** — грамматическая ошибка, которая в некоторых случаях может быть опиской.